# Content on MW widget should expand on first click, but shrinks back instead

Tags: javascript, html, widget, mediawiki, tumblr

For the past week, I've been working on a new [Tumblr widget](http://dixwell.referata.com/wiki/Widget%3aTumblr) on the Dixwell Dossier, a semantic wiki for my NaNoWriMo project. Part of it is based on [this JSFiddle experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/9ccjE/) brought up in another Stack Overflow question.

Current code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function growDiv() {
var growDiv = document.getElementById('grow');
if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
  growDiv.style.height = 0;
} else {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
  growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
}
document.getElementById("more-button").value=document.getElementById("more-button").value=='More'?'Less':'More';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.three-col {
   -moz-column-count: 3;
   -moz-column-gap: 20px;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
div iframe {width: 100%}
#more-button{border-style:none;background:none;font-size:16px;font-family:Merriweather;font-weight:bold;color:blue;margin: 0 0 10px 0;}
#grow input:checked{color:red;}
#more-button:hover{color:black;}
#grow {
-moz-transition: height 1.5s;
-ms-transition: height 1.5s;
-o-transition: height 1.5s;
-webkit-transition: height 1.5s;
transition: height 1.5s;
height: 800px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<div style="font-size: 125%; font-family: Verdana; border-radius: 5px; background-color: <!--{$bgcol|escape:'html'|default:'#780099'}-->; color: <!--{$textcol|escape:'html'|default:'white'}-->; margin-bottom: 8px; padding: 0.8em">The latest posts from <b><!--{$site|escape:'quotes'|default:'yahoo'}--></b> on Tumblr</div>
<div id='grow'>
<div class='measuringWrapper'>
<div class="three-col">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<!--{$site|escape:'quotes'|default:'yahoo'}-->.tumblr.com/js?num=15"></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="growDiv()" value="&#11015; More" id="more-button">
<div style="font-family: Verdana; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #6aa5cf; color: white; padding: 0.5em"><span class="plainlinks"><b>Never miss a post!</b> <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/register/follow/<!--{$site|escape:'html'|default:'yahoo'}-->"> Follow <b><!--{$site|escape:'quotes'|default:'yahoo'}--></b> now</a> • <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/">Sign in</a></span><span style="float: right">Powered by <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Tumblrfull.svg/50px-Tumblrfull.svg.png" alt="Tumblr logo"/></span></div>
```

Everything's going to plan, except for one little thing: The first time I click "More", the text area  shrinks back up and hides the posts. Only on the next click can I see all the posts; third click, and it hides everything back. Instead, they should go down and reveal the rest of the content, and go back to the original 800px height on next click.

Basically, what I want is:

↓ More (800px) → Less (100%) → More (800px),

not

↓ More (800px) → More (0) → Less (100%).

As it stands, I'm withholding further edits till I can get a solution here. Fixes, anyone?

(P.S. If you want to test this in the Dossier's Sandbox, you my have to wait a while: at this writing, Referata's servers are in slowdown mode. Code to use while editing:

{{#widget:tumblr}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's how you've programmed it to work.  Right at the top of your code, you have:

```javascript
if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
  growDiv.style.height = 0;
} else {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
  growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
}
```

In the `if` statement, you're checking `growDiv.clientHeight`.  If it's non-zero (and thus true), you're setting the height of the element to zero, otherwise you're setting it to equal the height of the `.measuringWrapper` div.

Now, you could simply replace the condition with, say, `if (growDiv.clientHeight > 800)`, and set the height to `"800px"` instead of `0` if the condition is true.  This would behave in funny ways if the height of the measuring wrapper was less than 800 px, though, so you might want to check for that first and treat it as a special case (perhaps disabling and hiding the button entirely).

Comment: "Well, that's how you've programmed it to work." More like: that's as far as I could take it pre-Stack. Getting very tired; I'll look it into it tomorrow.

Comment: Tested it out today—the button isn't budging, and I'm stuck with the same code I had before. Just remembered: I'm using [Techdirt](http://techdirt.com)'s "Expand/Collapse" button as a model. Although I'm trying to make heads and tails out of [_their_ code](https://cdn.techdirt.com/scripts/techdirt.js?v=2943-c345)....

Comment: Way to go, sir. But as I've specified in the code, the "More" part should be at the bottom, not the top.

Comment: Preview-tested it on the Dossier just this moment—and after a few fixes I did myself, the basic code's officially in place. Can't thank you enough, pal!

Comment: No problem. If the answer was helpful, consider clicking the check mark next to it to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). That'll mark your question as answered, and incidentally give both us a small bit of rep.